# How can I change css checkboxes of facet Api module of drupal?

Tags: search

I am using facet API, in left sidebar list of check boxes showing with padding in UL. I want to remove that. I search a lot and I found that it's come from java script.

```
<div id="block-facetapi-9pwgfld6g2ttzkp0vedb9x799jeznshr" class="block block-facetapi contextual-links-region clearfix">

        <h2 class="block-title">Fields of study</h2>
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="facetapi-facetapi----edit first"><a href="/?q=admin/config/search/facetapi/search_api%40job_index/block/field_job_study%3Aparents_all/edit&amp;destination=search/jobs">Configure facet display</a></li>
<li class="facetapi-facetapi----dependencies"><a href="/?q=admin/config/search/facetapi/search_api%40job_index/block/field_job_study%3Aparents_all/dependencies&amp;destination=search/jobs">Configure facet dependencies</a></li>
<li class="facetapi-facetapi----filters"><a href="/?q=admin/config/search/facetapi/search_api%40job_index/block/field_job_study%3Aparents_all/filters&amp;destination=search/jobs">Configure facet filters</a></li>
<li class="block-configure last"><a href="/?q=admin/structure/block/manage/facetapi/9PWgflD6G2ttZkP0vEDB9x799JeZnShr/configure&amp;destination=search/jobs">Configure block</a></li>
</ul></div>
  <a id="context-block-facetapi-9PWgflD6G2ttZkP0vEDB9x799JeZnShr" class="context-block editable edit-drop_jobs_search_job"></a><ul class="facetapi-facetapi-checkbox-links facetapi-facet-field-job-studyparents-all facetapi-processed" id="facetapi-facet-search-apijob-index-block-field-job-studyparents-all"><li class="leaf"><input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox"><a href="/?q=search/jobs/study-field/business-administration-management" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-inactive facetapi-checkbox-processed">Business administration / Management (1)<span class="element-invisible">Apply Business administration / Management filter</span></a></li>
<li class="leaf"><input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox"><a href="/?q=search/jobs/study-field/education-science" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-inactive facetapi-checkbox-processed">Education science (1)<span class="element-invisible">Apply Education science filter</span></a></li>
<li class="leaf"><input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox"><a href="/?q=search/jobs/study-field/visual-arts-design" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-inactive facetapi-checkbox-processed">Visual arts / Design (1)<span class="element-invisible">Apply Visual arts / Design filter</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is  div example it's calling css from live of bootstrap itself. Here using facet API. May I guess you can understand my problem. I can't able to change any CSS.  Its using Drupal module  to implement CSS.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned on (what I assume is) your previous question, questions about changing the look of HTML by using CSS are not dealt with here, as they're independent of Drupal. Drupal is just like any other web framework, it spits out HTML and CSS, at which point it's all about how the browser interprets and displays that. Drupal doesn't get involved in deciding what rules are more specific than others, what selectors will be used for what HTML elements, and so on. That's what you need to know to answer your question, so it's just off topic here. With the right edits, try Stack Overflow